# How do I resolve this non-unique table error when querying a database from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following code is issuing the following error message:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1066
Not unique table/alias: 'users'

SELECT * FROM (`users`, `users`) JOIN `user_profiles` ON `users`.`id` = `user_profiles`.`user_id`

Filename: /home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/models/cpanel/dashboard.php

Line Number: 38
```

Here is my code:

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Model {
  private $table_name = 'users'; // user accounts
  private $profile_table_name = 'user_profiles'; // user profiles

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $this->table_name = $ci->config->item('db_table_prefix', 'tank_auth').$this->table_name;
    $this->profile_table_name = $ci->config->item('db_table_prefix', 'tank_auth').$this->profile_table_name;
  }

 /**
  * Get user info by Id
  *
  * @param int
  * @param bool
  * @return object
  */
  function get_user_info($id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('user_profiles', 'users.id = user_profiles.user_id');

    $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
      return $data = $query->row();  
    }  else {
     return NULL;  
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: I know have this for my function and changed it because after looking at it I didn't need the extra table. I have an array ($data) of values being sent to my header but can I get away with sending it to the build that way it sends the array to all the partials.

```
function get_user_info($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('users.id', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) 
    {
        return $data = $query->row();    
    }
    else 
    {
        return NULL;    
    }

}
```

And this is from my controller I updated:

```
function index()
{
    $id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

    $data = $this->Dashboard->get_user_info($id);
    print_r($data);
    $this->template->set_layout('cpanel')->enable_parser(false);
    $this->template->set_partial('header', 'partials/header', $data);  
    $this->template->set_partial('sidebar', 'partials/sidebar');  
    $this->template->set_partial('content', 'partials/content');      
    $this->template->set_partial('footer', 'partials/footer');
    $this->template->build('/cpanel/index');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
SELECT * FROM (users, users)
```

I assume you're trying to join the table to itself, but you can't do that without giving aliases to the tables, otherwise the database doesn't know which side of the join you're referring to when you reference fields from it.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u1, users u2 
JOIN user_profiles ON u1.id = user_profiles.user_id
```

**Update:**

My above answer was written based on the error message, but I didn't notice the code link (I've since added the code to be inline with the question).

I'm not overly familiar with CI, but I have a feeling your problem lies in these three lines:

1. `private $table_name = 'users';`
2. `$this->db->from('users');`
3. `$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);`

In line 3, you're explicitly `get`ting `$this->table_name` which points to the `users` table as shown in line 1). However, by explicitly setting a `from` table, also pointed to `users`, in line 2, I think you're accidentally setting up a join between two tables. Since these two tables are both the same, and neither is aliased, it is resulting in an error. Try removing the `$this->db->from('users');` line and seeing if that resolves the issue.

**Update 2:**

I've been reading the [CodeIgniter user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html), and it seems you don't need to specify anything as a parameter to `$this->db->get()` when you're using building a query using methods like `from()`. I'd suggest just changing this line:

```
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
```

to this:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

See [this page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) for details.

Comment: Right but I'm trying to figure out how to put it into with the code I have with CI.

Comment: Right it just seems like everything I'm trying isn't working so I don't know what else to do.

Comment: @Jeff See my second update. It references the CI documentation. I think you just need to remove your parameter to the `get()` method.

Comment: @Jeff I can't see anything else I think could be causing the issue. Are you still getting the same error as before?

Comment: There is some updated stuff in the post, but I'm not getting the same error now however for some reason that data array is not getting used for the partials.  Because I keep getting an error saying that its an undefined variable on the partials line 16 where I"m echoing out the first_name value in the array. I echoed the $data variable at the top of the partials header page and it says undefined so for some reason I don't know why but its not going into the file correctly to be used. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Jeff It sounds like that's a separate issue. I would suggest opening a new question if you need help with this new issue (this answers is already cluttered enough and we should keep separate issues in separate questions anyway). If I've solved your "non-unique table" issue, please consider marking my answer accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I accidentally had: `$this->db->from( 'my_table' ); $query = $this->db->get( 'my_table' );`

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the Cartesian product of the users table with itself when you write `users,users` but not giving either of them an alias. I don't think you mean to be taking the Cartesian product at all. Try:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN user_profiles ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id
```

Comment: Right but I'm trying to figure out how to put it into with the code I have with CI.